# Integer based rounding issue

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

> Define the n-based integer rounding of an integer k to be the nearest multiple of n to k. If two multiples of n are equidistant use the greater one.
>
> the 4-based rounding of 5 is 4 because 5 is closer to 4 than it is to 8,
>
> the 5-based rounding of 5 is 5 because 5 is closer to 5 that it is to 10,
>
> the 4-based rounding of 6 is 8 because 6 is equidistant from 4 and 8, so the greater one is used
>
> Write a function named doIntegerBasedRounding that takes an integer array and rounds all its positive elements using n-based integer rounding.
> A negative element of the array is not modified and if n <=0, no elements of the array are modified. Finally you may assume that the
> array has at least two elements.

Problem that I am facing on two cases

```
({1, 2, 3, 4, 5},2) and ({-18, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},4)
```

I'm getting

```
[0, 2, 2, 4, 4] and [-18, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4]
```

Instead of

```
{2, 2, 4, 4, 6} and {-18, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4}
```

Here is my code

```
class doIntegerBasedRounding {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,9},5)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},3)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},-3)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{-1, -2, -3, -4, -5},3)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{-18, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},4)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},5)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},100)));
    }

public static int[] doIntegerBasedRounding(int[]a, int n){
    int temp;
    int[] b= new int[a.length];
    if(n<0)
        return a;
    for (int i =0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(a[i]<=0){
            b[i]=a[i];
        }
        else if(a[i]>0)    {
        temp = a[i]%n;
            if(temp>n/2) {
                b[i] = a[i] + (n - temp);}
            if (temp<=n/2){
                b[i]= a[i]-temp;
            }
            }
        }
    return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should switch your conditions, the first is `temp>=n/2` and the second `temp<n/2`

Comment: @garnulf Well, I tried doing that. It corrected result for aforementioned arrays but changed the result of other two arrays (3rd and 6th). Instead of **{0, 3, 3, 3, 6} and {0, 0, 5, 5, 5}**, I got **[3, 3, 3, 6, 6] and [0, 5, 5, 5, 5]**

Comment: You need to divide by 2.0 additionally otherwise 3/2 results in 1 not 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a different approach:

Call the value you're working with `v`:

1. Calculate the remainder when dividing `v` by `n`
2. Subtract this remainder from `v`; this results in rounding down
3. If the remainder is equal to or greater `n/2`, add `n`; this results in rounding up.

In code, for your particular problem structure:

```
public void doIntegerBasedRounding(int[] values, int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] > 0)
            {
                int rem = values[i]%n;
                values[i] = values[i] - rem + (rem>=n/2 ? n : 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change this code:

```
else if (a[i] > 0) {
    temp = a[i] % n;
    if (temp > n/2) {
        b[i] = a[i] + (n - temp);
    }
    if (temp <= n/2) {
        b[i] = a[i]-temp;
    }
}
```

To:

```
else if (a[i] > 0) {
    temp = a[i] / n;
    if ((n*temp - a[i]) * -1 < n*(temp+1) - a[i]) {
        b[i] = n*temp;
    }
    else {
        b[i] = n*(temp+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the comparison in the if block in the floating precision as as the compilers ignore the floating values in the int precision while division arithmetic operation.

so you just need to add a Floating element in the test expression.

below is the method which works fine:

```
private static int[] doIntegerBasedRounding(int[] is, int i) {
    i = Math.abs(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < is.length; j++) {
        int mod = is[j] % i;
        if (is[j] >= 0) {
            if (mod < i / 2f)
                is[j] -= mod;
            else
                is[j] += (i - mod);
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

running the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9 }, 5)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 2)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 3)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, -3)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { -1, -2, -3, -4, -5 }, 3)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { -18, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 4)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 100)));
    }
```

**produces output:**

```
[0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10]
[2, 2, 4, 4, 6]
[0, 3, 3, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 3, 3, 6]
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
[-18, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static long[] doIntegerBasedRounding(int[] ints, int i) {
    long[] result = new long[ints.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < ints.length; k++) {
        int item = ints[k];
        if (i == 0) {
            result[k] = 0;
            continue;
        } else if (i < 0) {
            i = -i;
        }
        if (item < 0) {
            result[k] = item;
            continue;
        }
        int multi = 0;
        int right = 0;
        while (right < item) {
            right = i*(++multi);
        }
        int left = i*(multi-1);

        if (right + left <= 2*item) {
            result[k] = right;
        } else {
            result[k] = left;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,9},5)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},2)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},3)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},-3)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{-1, -2, -3, -4, -5},3)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{-18, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},4)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},5)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doIntegerBasedRounding(new int []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},100)));

[0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10]
[2, 2, 4, 4, 6]
[0, 3, 3, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 3, 3, 6]
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
[-18, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[0, 0, 5, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[]  doIntegerBasedRounding(int[ ] a, int n)
{ 
    if(n<0)
    return a;
     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>0)
        if(a[i]<n)
        {
         if(a[i]<n-a[i])
         {
          a[i]=0;   
        }
         else{
           a[i]=n;  
         } 
        }

        else{
         int j=0;
         int num=n;
         int state=1;
            while(state!=0)
            {
                 num=n;
              num=num*j;
                if(num>=a[i])
                {
                    int y=num-a[i];
                     int x=a[i]-n;

                    if(y<=x)
                     a[i]=num;
                   else 
                      a[i]=n;
                  state=0;
                }
             j++;   
            }

             }


    }
 return a;    
}
```

Comment: add some description too

Answer (score -1):

my code:

```
public static void doIntegerBasedRounding(int[]a,int n) {

    System.out.print("{ ");
    if(n>0) {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i]>=0) {
            if(n%2==0) {
            if(a[i]%n >= n/2) {
        a[i]=((a[i]/n)*n)+n;
        System.out.print(a[i]+ ", ");
        }else {
            a[i]=(a[i]/n)*n;
            System.out.print(a[i]+", ");
        }
        }else {   
            if(a[i]%n > n/2) {
            a[i]=((a[i]/n)*n)+n;
            System.out.print(a[i]+ ", ");
            }else {
                a[i]=(a[i]/n)*n;
                System.out.print(a[i]+", ");
            }
        }
        }else {
            System.out.print(a[i]+", ");
        }
      }
    }else {
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
                System.out.print(a[i]+ ", ");
            }
        }
    System.out.print("}");
}
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use this **Method** to get nearest multiple of **5** to a given **integer**.

```
private int giveNearestMul5(int givenValue){
    int roundedNum = 0;
    int prevMul5, nextMul5;
    prevMul5 = givenValue - givenValue%5;
    nextMul5 = prevMul5 + 5;
    if ((givenValue%5!=0)){
        if ( (givenValue-prevMul5) < (nextMul5-givenValue) ){
            roundedNum = prevMul5;
        } else {
            roundedNum = nextMul5;
        }
    } else{
        roundedNum = givenValue;
    }

    return roundedNum;
}
```

Comment: That’s not what the OP was asking about.